# Able to connect Adhoc WiFi network, but terminal says no wlan0

Tags: wireless, network-monitoring

I have a WiFi and a Ethernet card on my laptop.

I've created an adhoc network and using internet via lan. 

I am able to connect my adhoc network, but, when I do ifconfig, it does not display any WiFi interface.

```
ifconfig -s
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500 0     13115      0      0 0          8157      0      0      0 BMRU
eth1       1500 0         0      0      0 0            10     19      0      0 BRU
lo        16436 0       475      0      0 0           475      0      0      0 LRU
virbr0     1500 0         0      0      0 0            24      0      0      0 BMRU
```

I want to be able to start/stop my wireless interface from terminal, but can't `sudo ifup wlan0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo iwlist scan` in the terminal. It will list the names of the wireless device names on your system.

I don't know if it was an update to the ubuntu naming conventions, but when I tested my machine it was using `eth1` as the wireless lan device.

The above command will get you the proper name (which by your output is either `eth0` or `eth1`), then just use that name when performing commands (`ifconfig eth1 up`).

Comment: It's eth1 on my machine as well.

Comment: Thanks @brian-graham , I can scan using eth1 interface...

Comment: No problem @RavishTiwari, glad I could help.

Comment: sad part is mine is a broadcom STA driver and 'Monitor' mode is not allowed :(